# Similar cheeses to Queso fresco in Belgium?

Tags: substitutions

I am a mexican~american living in Belgium, what would be the best substitute for the Fresco mexican cheese? Thank you!

Comment: very related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11118/cheeses-similar-to-queso-fresco

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cheeses similar to queso fresco](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11118/cheeses-similar-to-queso-fresco)

Answer (score 1):

I would say: soft cheeses, like here is a easy way to make instant cheese: 16oz. Cup organic farm milk, 4 oz. White. Vinegar, pour into a pot and boil on stove top 5 mins. Then turn off fire- and let sit uncovered, for a hour untell cold 
Pour liquid milk into a cheese cloth in to a bowl.
The clumps be cream cheese - great for crackers.
I like to keep those cake spread small containers with blue lid and make cream cheese to carry along in back pack -with crackers - with a spoon.
Great for picnic or hiking also when one walks alot.

Comment: UHT milk also makes great fresh cheese, if you can't get the 'real' stuff.